# code is not outputting anything in visual studio mac even with readline

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-mac

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace HelloWorld
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] val = { 2, 1, 6, 3, 4 };
            Console.WriteLine(val.Length);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to build the file, it just says "build successful" and does display the `val.length`.
I tried everything but nothing is working to display the length.

Comment: it is c# running in vs code

Comment: Why did you tag it with JavaScript? If you literally tried everything to solve it, what is your question?